# How to properly get index from index path in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios

I have a one dimensional array of images that I am feeding to a UICollectionView.
The collection view is just one section composed of the elements in the array.
when I click a cell and `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` gets fired off and I do a print out of the indexPath I get values like [0,0] for element 0 in row 0 but then the very next element in that row is [0,5].

How can I map the indexPath to my array like the way `UITableView`'s [indexPath row] matches directly to the corresponding index?

Comment: What code are you using to print out the indexPath?

Comment: The collection view is probably aligned wrong, if you were tapping the item to the right, tap the one below and vice versa...

Comment: For the each item in their section, you could multiply the number of sections with indexPath.section and add indexpath.row to get the index for the 1 dimensional array.

example:
for a 4X4 grid,
(0,0) is ((4*0)+0)
(0,1) is ((4*0)+1)
(0,2) is ((4*0)+2)
.
.
.
(4,3) is ((4*3)+3)
(4,4) is ((4*3)+4)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've never used them, but my understanding is that the two properties of a UICollectionView's indexPath are section and item, not section and row like in a UITableView.

Comment: I logged both indexPath.row and indexPath.row, and only to find they were exactly the same...

Comment: @Calios Well I'd imagine if you logged the same thing twice, you'd get the same result.

Answer (score 10):

To Retrieve item index you need to use indexPath.item(for UICollectionView) not indexPath.row(it's for UITableView)